# Getting routes match error even if the routes are different

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, routes, asp.net-core-3.1

I am getting an error like `request has been matched with the multiple endpoints` even if I have different routes defined for `httpGet` operations.

The code looks like as below,

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class CrmManagementController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("projects")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ProjectInfo(
        [FromServices] ICrmProjects crmProjects,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _ = crmProjects ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(crmProjects));

        var vantagepointProjects = await crmProjects.GetAllVantagepointProjectsByNumberAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Ok(vantagepointProjects.Values);
    }

    [HttpGet("pursuits")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> PursuitInfo(
        [FromServices] ICrmProjects crmProjects,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        _ = crmProjects ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(crmProjects));

        var vantagepointPursuits = await crmProjects.GetAllVantagepointPursuitsByNumberAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Ok(vantagepointPursuits.Values);
    }
}
```

Please let me know why I am getting the error and any suggestions to avoid the problem.

**Update:** Error details

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[13]
      Connection id "0HN1DKQDVNS2Q", Request id "0HN1DKQDVNS2Q:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
      Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

      HTTP: GET /
      HTTP: GET / at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ReportAmbiguity(Span`1 candidateState)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.ProcessFinalCandidates(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DefaultEndpointSelector.Select(HttpContext httpContext, Span`1 candidateState)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.MatchAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
```

Below is the configuration in program.cs file

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapGet("/", () => "This is the sample project");
});
```

Comment: Your code is fine. Are you sure these controller actions cause the mentioned issue? Have you try to comment either of these action methods and see the issue happened again?

Comment: Hi @kumar425, could you pls share the detailed error message? It would tell you which endpoints the request match.

Comment: @Rena, I have updated the question to include the error details and config in the program.cs file.

Comment: @YongShun, Surprisingly, I am getting the same error even If I comment on one of the action methods, and I have updated the question to include the details.

Comment: From the exception message, it seems the path "/" is conflicted. What if you remove the line `endpoints.MapGet("/", () => "This is the sample project");` and see does it work?

Comment: @YongShun, Thank you, I did the same and it got resolved. You can post this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception message mentions that there are conflicting endpoints/URLs for "/".

By removing this line:

```cs
endpoints.MapGet("/", () => "This is the sample project");
```

from the `app.UseEndpoints()` should resolve your issue.